# how to transfer object list to array and assign index number in the field name in dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I have below object list

```
[
    {
    "goods_code": "A27JJ",
    "imageCount": 3,
    "color_id": 8,
    "display_sec" : 2,
    "image": "d1"
   },
 {
    "goods_code": "A27JJ",
    "imageCount": 2,
    "color_id": 8,
    "display_sec" : 1,
    "image": "d2"
},
 {
    "goods_code": "A27JJ",
    "imageCount": 1,
    "color_id": 1,
    "display_sec" : 1,
    "image": "d3"
}
]
```

may i know how to transform below object data in dataweave,
it need to assign index number for color_id, image_id base on image count

```
{
    "goods_code": "A27JJ",
    "imageCount": 2,    
      color_id_1: 8,
      display_sec_1: 2,
      image_1 : d1,
      color_id_2: 8,
      display_sec_2: 1,
      image_2: d2,
      color_id_3: 1,
      display_sec_3 : 1
      image_3: d3
}
```

Comment: Why is imageCount 2 in the output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this script though it does not account for the imageCount in the output

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload groupBy ($.goods_code) mapObject {
          goods_code: $.goods_code[0],
          ($ map {
                 ("color_id_" ++ ($$+1)) : $.color_id,
                 ("display_sec_"++ ($$+1)) : $.display_sec,
                 ("image_"++ ($$+1)) : $.image 
          })
}
```

**Output**

```
{
  "goods_code": "A27JJ",
  "color_id_1": 8,
  "display_sec_1": 2,
  "image_1": "d1",
  "color_id_2": 8,
  "display_sec_2": 1,
  "image_2": "d2",
  "color_id_3": 1,
  "display_sec_3": 1,
  "image_3": "d3"
}
```